# How to reduce space between columns in a horizontal legend [Python]

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like to reduce space between legend columns (An example is shown in the attached image).
So, what I want to do is,

[before]

(Sym.)A ------ (Sym.)B ------ (Sym.)C ------ (Sym.)D

[after]

(Sym.)A -- (Sym.)B -- (Sym.)C -- (Sym.)D

Is there a way to do it?
(e.g., `plt.legend(ncol=4, [a hidden parameter??])`)

Thanks!

Image of the current output:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the description of `columnspacing` from [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html). You can try:

```
plt.legend(ncol=4, columnspacing=0.8)
```